# Put a million rows from flat file to blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, hyperledger

I have a flat file with each row containing records such as

```
AX101 12345 PQR 101
AX102 18390 XYZ 091
AX101 81249 PQR 871
```

My setup has a few machines connected in a network on Hyperledger with vagrant and docker.

**Test 1** 
For this test, I am running just one validating peer that should read the flat file with over million such rows and put each row as a new block. The intention is to test the speed for doing so. What could be best way to achieve this?

*Approach 1* : The code could be in GoLang sitting inside a smart contract

*Approach 2* : A seperate "reader" in another language that sends the data to the validating peer via APIs (would be slower, I think)

**Test 2** 
Once (hopefully) when all the data is on blockchain, I need to parse all entries for say AX101, speed is not a concern here but picking up all entries is.

Any pointers would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes you are talking about the Hyperledger fabric:

There is no way to avoid writing a chaincode (smart contract) to add the data to the database. All data in the blockchain is owned by the chaincode that created it, and can only be accessed by the chaincode that created it. There is no concept of shared data, or simply writing data into the blockchain. So you need to do Approach 2, and send the data to a chaincode via its "add new record" method (which you will create).

To access the data you would create a query method for your chaincode. You can control the speed of parsing in Test 2 by the way you store the data. There is Godoc documentation for the database APIs available to the chaincode here: https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim

Comment: Yes, trying this in Hyperledger for now, but it would be great to achieve this in Ethereum as well. I will try your suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 1):

**Test 1**
There are several arguments why Approach 1 is not the best solution. 
First of all, if you will try to run initial import in GoLang from smart contract, this import will be executed as a single transaction.
Doesn’t matter where this import is initiated (in “Init” or in “Invoke” methods of your chaincode) in both cases you will bump into “timeout” issue.
The second - this approach ruins the idea of blockchain. Smart-contract should not pull data from external sources (files) because anybody can modify them, as a result entire chain will go into inconsistent state.

**Test 2**
Hyperledger is not designed to be a database and “parse all entries for say AX101” is not it’s primary goal. 
Provided description is quite limited, nevertheless there are several ideas for how to "emulate" this behavior:

Possible option 1:
You can try to use “RANGE_QUERY_STATE” - it will work only if you try to run search by first part of the string “AX101….”

Possible option 2:
Use “AX101” as a key and {“12345 PQR 101”, “81249 PQR 871”} as a value. Such data structure can be build at import time. Works only if you are not going to run queries using other part of the string.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I agree that the approach ruins the idea of blockchain completely but I am testing this in a secure environment where the flat file is produced via trusted mechanism. The main idea is just to test the performance as of now.  Regarding the Test 2, is this not what Bitcoin network does.. parse ledger information about a certain public address and come up with available balance?

Comment: @bitxor  you should look at this slightly different; Hyperledger uses the blockchain to record its transactions, next to that it has RoxDB, a key-value store to persist more complex data structures that you can put in there by 'invocation transactions'. The phrasing available balance makes me think of cryptocurrencies, which is a possible use of Hyperledger but a very small one. In that case you would do as suggested by Sergey in option#2 where you store the public identifier as key and the balance as value.